# laravel routes. how to make a route that match multiple prams?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

now i have routes :

```
Route::get('blog','BlogController@index');
Route::get('blog/pram1','BlogController@index'); 
Route::get('blog/pram1/pram2','BlogController@index');
```

i need to make a route that allow me to use any number of prams without specifying the exact number of prams...  EX:

```
www.site.com/blog/pram1/pram2/pram3/pram4/pram5/......
```

just need a way to specify a route that begin with (blog) then any number of prams after that gets redirected to the same controller method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, I recommend to use this pattern:

```
www.site.com/blog?pram1=foo&pram2=bar
```

So keep only

```
Route::get('blog','BlogController@index');
```

Then in your controller

```
public function index()
{
    // www.site.com/blog?pram1=foo&pram2=bar
    $param1 = Input::get('param1'); // return 'foo'
    $param2 = Input::get('param2'); // return 'bar'
    $param3 = Input::get('param3'); // return null
}
```

---

**Update**

If you need to keep your route as it is, you may try:

```
Route::get('blog/{params?}','BlogController@index')->where('params', '.*');
```

Then in your controller

```
var_dump(Request::segment(2)); // return value of param1, null if doesn't exist
```

Comment: i knew this but it doesn't work.
 i need it to use a previously written code that uses this strategy in prams.

Comment: just need a way to specify on route that begin with (blog) then any number of prams after that gets redirected to the same controller method...